# Does Bhagwat Mahapuran has a routine and daily timing that one should follow

Tags: bhagavata-purana

When to wake up ?
When to sleep ?
What time to eat ?
Is all this mentioned in the Bhawawat Mahapuran ?

Comment: No. This is not the subject matter of Puranas. This is the subject matter of Dharmashastras